# Close reason are using HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons

In the "community-specific reason" close reasons, all links to an SE site or article are using HTTP instead of HTTPs.

This applies to all the close reason that include links in them:

- Not about Ubuntu
- Bug report
- EoL questions - *The link to the Ubuntu Wiki is already HTTPS, but the link to the Q/A on Ask Ubuntu is not*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Invoking the great powers of [JNat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/208518/jnat), this issue has been resolved smoothly. Thank you for bringing it to our attention.

Comment: To be fair, I noticed it because of your edit on my other question xD